# What would be the right way (grammar) for a law firm to wish a client a happy birthday

Tags: grammar

Would you say…

Johnson & Johnson wish you a happy birthday

or

Johnson & Johnson wishes you a happy birthday

I don't believe these are complete sentences and have read that a company really should be more formal when trying to send a message because a company can't really wish as it is not a person.

Maybe something along the lines of…

All of us at Johnson & Johnson would like to wish you a happy birthday

I am just trying to find a short correct way of stating this.

Thanks

Comment: look at Merriam-Webster's dictionary of English usage (on Google Books) for the entry on this topic.

Comment: The right way (etiquette) would be for them not to do it at all. I utterly despise commercial organisations that intrusively use personal data in this way.

Comment: ... And it's so false. 'All of us at Gollum & Underhill, except Joe who's away at the moment and FF who doesn't go in for this sort of thing, would like to wish you a happy birthday.'

Comment: To some of the responses, what we are trying to accomplish is good wishes to our client base, it is in no way shape or form advertisement as it is not a cold call list it is to our existing client base.

Answer (score 1):

I think that any of these would be acceptable, but, as you say, a company is not a person, and so the last sentence sounds much more genuine.

I would go with 'All of us at Johnson & Johnson wish you a happy birthday.' Shorter, but still correct.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

"We wish you a Happy Birthday"

(signed) All of us at Johnson & Johnson

Comment: By the time they find Joe and blackmail FF, it'll be too late to send the card.

Comment: Edwin, you seem to have an axe to grind- please do it elsewhere.